# Cannot call function

Tags: python, function

I can't seem to get my global variable Guesses into the function. The program is just skipping over the function.

```
def getList(Guesses):
    alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    aList = list(abc)
    k = 0
    while k < len(Guesses):
        if Guesses[k] in aList:
            aList.remove(Guesses[k])
            k += 1
        else:
            k += 1
    return ''.join(aList)

Guesses = ['a', 'b', 'f', 'd', 'e', 'g']
```

Comment: if you feel like you're struggling with the basics, maybe check out some python tutorial like https://www.w3schools.com/python/ or https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/. you'll also find some more ways to improve/shorten your code after completing them.

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Read the error: `NameError: name 'abc' is not defined`.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I'm taking a course as we speak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def getList(Guesses):
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
aList = list(alphabet)#Chnage the variable Name
k = 0
while k < len(Guesses):
    if Guesses[k] in aList:
        aList.remove(Guesses[k])
        k += 1
    else:
        k += 1
return ''.join(aList)
```

Guesses = ['a', 'b', 'f', 'd', 'e', 'g']
#lastly call your function
getList(Guesses)

Comment: Welcome .,always Try To Call The User Define Function ...keep Learning ..All The Best

Comment: Hallo, please give more details : what you want to do ? What did you try so far ?

Comment: Hello, All. I was simply trying to create a system where I eliminate the letters in guesses from the alphabet list. I was able to do so however, when I change the name from Guesses to lettersGuessed, python tutorial stops working for me for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

You have to *call* the function:

```
Guesses = ['a', 'b', 'f', 'd', 'e', 'g']
print(getList(Guesses))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code doing what I need it to do. :)
Eliminating the letters in guesses from the alphabet list.
Thanks for the support.
K

```
def getList(Guesses):
    alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    aList = list(alphabet)
    k = 0
    while k < len(Guesses):
        if Guesses[k] in aList:
            aList.remove(Guesses[k])
            k += 1
        else:
            k += 1
    return ''.join(aList)

Guesses = ['a', 'b', 'f', 'd', 'e', 'g']
print(getList(Guesses))
```